# After push to remote, the default uwsgi changed the location

Tags: python, git, pip

I have a Django project with the local repo, In my local git repo, I installed the `uwsgi` in my project `venv/lib/python3.5/site-packages`, and I push my local repo to remote repo use:

```
(venv) james_pro:myProject ldl$ git push remote_repo 
ldl@101.120.32.16's password: 
Counting objects: 10279, done.
Delta compression using up to 4 threads.
Compressing objects: 100% (8966/8966), done.
Writing objects: 100% (10279/10279), 18.43 MiB | 886.00 KiB/s, done.
Total 10279 (delta 2774), reused 0 (delta 0)
To 103.200.32.76:/home/ldl/repo/Qiyun02
   551388c..ef0a95f  master -> master
```

in my local repo I show the uwsgi:

```
(venv) james_pro: $ pip3 show uwsgi
Name: uWSGI
Version: 2.0.17
Summary: The uWSGI server
Home-page: https://uwsgi-docs.readthedocs.io/en/latest/
Author: Unbit
Author-email: info@unbit.it
License: GPL2
Location: /Users/lll/Desktop/myProject/Project/myProject/venv/lib/python3.5/site-packages
Requires: 
Required-by:
```

You see its under my project's `venv`.

But in my remote repo, if I show the uwsgi, it will shows the

```
(venv) [root@www myProject]# pip3 show uwsgi 
Name: uWSGI
Version: 2.0.17
Summary: The uWSGI server
Home-page: https://uwsgi-docs.readthedocs.io/en/latest/
Author: Unbit
Author-email: info@unbit.it
License: GPL2
Location: /usr/local/Python3/lib/python3.5/site-packages
Requires: 
Required-by:
```

this location is `/usr/local/Python3/lib/python3.5/site-packages`, not the venv path.

How can I solve this issue? because I want to use uwsgi to connect the django.